# Zero value of program counter

Tags: arm, crash-dumps

program counter (PC) has the address of the currently executing instruction or next instruction in line. for ARMV5, its the former case.

I have encountered the crashes where PC (R15) value is zero. I was wondering if someone can tell me the significance of that. And is there some way (some other register) to find out the address of current instruction.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the source?  What language?

Answer (score 5):

Some code probably tried to call a null function-pointer. Check the stack to see where the call came from.

Comment: In particular, on ARM, the link register (r14) will usually give you the PC of the caller.

Answer (score 1):

In general (ARM terminology ) it would be a prefetch abort. 
Means cpu is trying to read (pre-fetch) instruction from illgela address which caused this.
you can try to see how tht mem location has become invlid to find out more on the cause !